# run an IF statement once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, conditional-statements

I have an age value which I'm using as a condition to enter an IF statement. The IF statement populates random values in to a field (this is a childs math game). After the fields are populated the user can enter their answers and then check them using a 'Check Answers' button. Once the 'Check Answers' block is run the IF statement gets ran again(!), which causes the math problems to change - new random values are created.

How can I prevent the IF statement from running after the page has already loaded; causing the values to change each time the 'Check Answers' button is clicked?

Here is is the relevant javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var getAge = localStorage.getItem('setAge');

    var userResponse = new Array();
    var answer = new Array();

    if (getAge >= 1 && getAge <= 7) {
        var operator = new Array('+', '-');

        for (var counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++) {
            var index = Math.round(Math.random());
            var1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
            var2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

            // these add the values to the mathQuestions.aspx
            $('#a' + counter).text(var1);
            $('#b' + counter).text(operator[index]);
            $('#c' + counter).text(var2);

            answer[counter] = eval(var1 + operator[index] + var2);
        }

    // this stores the users answers in userResponse[]
    for (var counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++) {
        $('#d' + counter).change(function () {
            for (var counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++) {
                userResponse[counter] = $('#d' + counter).val();
                // window.alert("userResponse = " + userResponse[counter]);
            }
        });
    }

    // Button3 = 'Check Answers'
    $('#Button3').click(function () {
        for (var counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++) {
            window.alert('userResponse after checking the answers = ' + userResponse[counter]);

            if (answer[counter] != userResponse[counter]) {
                $('#span' + counter).val(answer[counter]);
            }
        }
    });
 });
```

I'm still learning all of this so I could have others errors that are contributing to my problem. To my knowledge the root problem is caused by the IF statement running again. Also, in case it's relevant I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web using some ASP controls (table, buttons, input, etc).

Comment: it should only run once, when the page load is completed, and then not again. if you really want, you could set a sentinel variable, e.g. `var already_ran = false;` , then set it to true after your if() completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the issue is not within the code you've posted, but within your HTML; Based on the code you've posted does contain a click-event, but this could never cause the 'randomize'-part to be ran again.

Could it be that your HTML looks like:

```
<form>
<button>Check answers</button>
</form>
```

or

```
<form>
<input type="submit" value="Check answers">
</form>
```

Having a `button` or `submit` inside a form-attribute results in a 'submit-action' when you hit the button. The result is that you first see the alert-message from the click-event. Next the page is reloaded and the whole `document.ready()` script will be executed again.

A simple solution could be:

```
$('#Button3').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    /* ... */
}
```

This stops the form from submitting.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Wouter you were completely right. It was the 'submit-action' you were referencing. You are lucky we're not close to each other or I'd be sending an open-mouth kiss your way. I have been struggling with this for days. Thank you so much!! 

(just kidding about the open-mouth kiss part)